# Question about lower bound and upper bound key collision

Tags: hash, collision-resistance

I'm reading [this article](https://eprint.iacr.org/2011/191.pdf) and I have a doubt in the page 7. First I going to describe the required definitions and next I formulate my question.

Let be $$F(n)=\{f_k: \{0,1\}^n\rightarrow \{0,1\}^n| k\in \{0,1\}^n\}$$  a family function.

**Definition:** The upper bound $\kappa$ is defined as follows: For each pair $(x,k)$, there is at most $\kappa-1$ different keys $k_1,\cdots,k_{\kappa-1}$, which are also different from $k$, such that $f_k(x)=f_{k_i}(x)$ for $i=0\cdots,\kappa-1$. Equivalent we define the lower bound $\kappa '$: For each pair $(x,k)$, there is at most $\kappa  '-1$ different keys $k_1,\cdots,k_{\kappa  '-1}$, which are also different from $k$, such that $f_k(x)=f_{k_i}(x)$ for $i=0\cdots,\kappa '-1$

My question is with this claim:

> The values $\kappa$ and $\kappa ′$ restrict the number of different
>   images $y$ some preimage $x$ can be mapped to by functions in $F(n)$, i.e.
>
> $$\dfrac{2^n}{\kappa}\leq |\{f_k(x): k \in \{0,1\}^n\}|\leq
> \dfrac{2^n}{\kappa '}$$
>
> for all $x \in \{0,1\}^n$

Why $|\{f_k(x): k \in \{0,1\}^n\}|\geq\dfrac{2^n}{\kappa}$, resp. $(\leq \dfrac{2^n}{\kappa '})$? 
I make this question because the number maximum of equals images are $\kappa$ and the total number of keys is $2^n$ then for me there are at least $2^n-\kappa$ diffentent preimages.

Answer (score 3):

Remember that the bounds are defined for every key. This means, there will be a first set of keys that contains at least $\kappa'$ and at most $\kappa$ keys that all map $x$ to the same $y$. Now, every key not in this set has to be in another set with the same size bounds that maps within which every key maps $x$ to the same $y$ which is different from all the $y_i$ the other sets map to. And so on.

Hence, there are at least $\frac{2^n}{\kappa}$ such sets of keys. All keys in such a set map $x$ to the same $y$ which is different form the $y_i$'s the other sets map to. Consequently, there are at least $\frac{2^n}{\kappa}$ different $y_i$.

Similarly, there are at most $\frac{2^n}{\kappa'}$ such sets of keys and accordingly no more than $\frac{2^n}{\kappa'}$ different values $y_i$.